# List out arrays inside array that have common elements

Tags: arrays, perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @array = ( ['John', 'Apple', 6],
              ['Adam', 'Banana', 7],
              ['Cass', 'Orange', 7],
              ['Brad', 'Lemon', 6],
              ['Lisa', 'Grape', 5] );
```

The columns are name, fruits and age. How to use grep or any other commands to extract out entries with the same age, and push it into another array? For example, if I want to extract entries with age 7, the result array will be something like this:

```
@age7 = ( ['Adam', 'Banana', 7],
          ['Cass', 'Orange', 7] );
```

How do I achieve this if my task has few thousands of entries (arrays inside array)?

Comment: `my @age7 = grep $_->[2] ==7, @array;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to use a hash, like so:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @array = ( ['John', 'Apple', 6],
              ['Adam', 'Banana', 7],
              ['Cass', 'Orange', 7],
              ['Brad', 'Lemon', 6],
              ['Lisa', 'Grape', 5] );

my %hash;
for (@array) {
    push @{ $hash{$_->[2]} }, $_;
}
print Dumper $hash{7};
```

This will however differentiate between numbers like `7` and `7.0`, since hash keys are strings. If that is a problem, you can always loop over the keys and use a comparison, such as `if ($key >= 7.1 and $key <= 7)`

Comment: Thanks for the response! However, how do I remove duplicates of arrays inside the hash? For example when I print @{$hash{7}}:
`$VAR1 = [
          [
            'Adam',
            'Banana',
            7
          ],
          [
            'Adam',
            'Banana',
            7
          ],
          [
            'Cass',
            'Orange',
            7
          ]
        ];`
How do I remove one of the ['Adam','Banana']?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Deduping can also be done with hashes. But that is another question.